# How can I see how many posts are truly in the review queue?

Tags: support, review-queues

This question: [Would ELU like to start a trial of only need 3 votes to close/reopen a question?](https://english.meta.stackexchange.com/q/13558/73636) mentions that the review queue is too long, approximately 160 posts. Since reading that, I have upped the number of posts I have reviewed from zero to 60 (but it took me longer than 10 seconds!).

It now looks to me as if there are 137 posts that need reviewing (some new ones have been flagged). However, the ones I have voted on are no longer included in the total shown to me. Not all of the ones I voted on had reached the threshold, so were still waiting for other users to vote on them.

How can I see how many posts are really waiting to be reviewed?

[image]

Comment: There are currently 146 questions https://english.stackexchange.com/review click **all reviews** in the  REVIEW QUEUES link. Bravo for helping to keep the site clean.

Comment: @Mari-LouA I can't find the word "all" on the reviews page. I currently see 0 against all categories except Close Votes which says 113.

Comment: Then that means you don't have that so-called "privilege". Look at the help centre to see how much rep a user needs to see those stats.

Comment: Maybe it's at 10,000: access to moderator tools - Access reports, delete questions, review reviews. It seems strange to separate the privilege to vote and to see an accurate representation of the vote queues.

Comment: Indeed, having to earn 10K before being granted the privilege (never really liked the term) to view the history  of the review queue seems a bit daft. What harm can come from a 3K user seeing the number of remaining posts?

Comment: Please confirm whether or not curiousdannii's method, described below, worked for you. I tried it myself using my Stack Overflow account, which has a rep of 105,  but as I lack the rep to review, could not see any link whereas my lengthier process worked each time.

Comment: @Mari-LouA Yes, if you are not logged in, you can see the queue numbers (just greyed out). As of posting this comment, when not logged in and incognito I can see 91 in the close queue whereas when logged in I can see only 50.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The easiest way is to open the review page in an incognito/private browser window.

Answer (score 0):

There is another way to view the review numbers without having 10K rep, I'm not sure if it's a bug or not, but nevertheless it worked for me.

Recently, as a 101 rep user I proposed four separate edits on Stack Overflow, of which two were accepted. I then visited my profile page and clicked on:

*activity* –>*all actions* –>*suggestions* –>*rejected edit*

At the top left hand corner of the page, click on the **Review** link, and voilà this will take you to the review page, and you (pl) will see all the numbers of impending reviews for each task.

Comment: As a 101 rep user you can't vote, so you will always see the true values.

Comment: @CJDennis I can't review on SO because I don't have enough rep, so I don't have *any* access the review queue, I do not see any number despite being incognito, whether logged on or not and the RQ was still hidden. That was my point of my comments to you and curiosdannii, going incognito seems to work if you already have enough rep to review in the first place.

Comment: This link works for me when not logged in: https://stackoverflow.com/review Just put `/review` at the end of any Stack Exchange address.

Comment: @CJDennis sorry for late reply, missed your message in the inbox. I think your method is by far the best way. It's really easy.